# Espeak library pcm.c:2495 unknown pcm bluealsa - raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, noobs

I'm currently working on a project using espeak 
I fixed the first issues with devices using this tutorial
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=136974

but i'm left with what is below after using espeak anywhere (python code or terminal), the tutorial I used and no tutorials I can find cover this information what could I do to fix this or does anyone know of any tutorials that cover it?

Code used to give error

```
espeak "hello there"
```

Error given

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4996:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4996:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
```

I installed `bluealsa` but still throws the same error.

Note: this doesnt stop the espeak from working it will still read out the given string but the error message thrown crashes my programs.

Comment: Try typing `sudo apt-get install bluealsa` on the command line.

Comment: it installed bluealsa but still throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

I will update if I have any better advice after more research, but just suppress the string message by redirecting them to the bit-bucket:

```
espeak "hello there" 2> /dev/null
```